# message in my react app how to solve this

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, reduce, redux-thunk

It keeps showing me this message in react, redux app
I have tried to fix it but nothing work and actually I can't know what is the problem in my code

**Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): props.setAlerts is not a function**

This is my store

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './reducers';

const initialState = {};

const middleware = [thunk];

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  initialState,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
);

export default store;
```

This is my function

```
import { SET_ALERT, REMOVE_ALERT } from './types';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

export const setAlerts = (masg, alertType) => dispatch => {
  const id = uuidv4();
  dispatch({
    type: SET_ALERT,
    payload: { masg, alertType, id }
  });
};
```

this is my reducer

```
import { SET_ALERT, REMOVE_ALERT } from '../actions/types';

const initialState = [];

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  const { type, payload } = action;
  switch (type) {
    case SET_ALERT:
      return [...state, payload];
    case REMOVE_ALERT:
      return state.filter(alert => alert.id !== payload);
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

this is my action types

```
export const SET_ALERT = 'SET_ALERT';
export const REMOVE_ALERT = 'REMOVE_ALERT';
```

This is my component I want to use my function in

```
import React, { Fragment, useState } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { setAlerts } from '../../actions/alert';

export const Register = props => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    name: '',
    email: '',
    password: '',
    password2: ''
  });

  const { name, email, password, password2 } = formData;

  const onChange = e =>
    setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });

  const onSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (password !== password2) {
      props.setAlerts('Password dont match', 'danger');
    } else {
      console.log('Succes');
    }
  };
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <section className='container'>
        <h1 className='large text-primary'>Sign Up</h1>
        <p className='lead'>
          <i className='fas fa-user'></i> Create Your Account
        </p>
        <form className='form' onSubmit={e => onSubmit(e)}>
          <div className='form-group'>
            <input
              type='text'
              placeholder='Name'
              name='name'
              value={name}
              onChange={e => onChange(e)}
              required
            />
          </div>
          <div className='form-group'>
            <input
              type='email'
              placeholder='Email Address'
              name='email'
              value={email}
              onChange={e => onChange(e)}
            />
            <small className='form-text'>
              This site uses Gravatar so if you want a profile image, use a
              Gravatar email
            </small>
          </div>
          <div className='form-group'>
            <input
              type='password'
              placeholder='Password'
              name='password'
              minLength='6'
              value={password}
              onChange={e => onChange(e)}
            />
          </div>
          <div className='form-group'>
            <input
              type='password'
              placeholder='Confirm Password'
              name='password2'
              minLength='6'
              value={password2}
              onChange={e => onChange(e)}
            />
          </div>
          <input type='submit' className='btn btn-primary' value='Register' />
        </form>
        <p className='my-1'>
          Already have an account? <Link to='/login'>Sign In</Link>
        </p>
      </section>
    </Fragment>
  );
};


export default connect(null, { setAlerts })(Register);
```

Comment: It's not a prop, it's being imported. Just do `setAlerts('...')`.

Comment: i did this because i use redux so it have to pass to connect and then pass it to my component as a props

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Redux prop is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60607989/react-redux-prop-is-undefined)

Comment: As in the tagged duplicate, you are doing both a named and default export. This means if you import the component as default, it will have the extra props given by the `connect` HOC. If you import it as named, it will not. Make sure you import it like `import Register from './path/to/Register'`

Comment: thank alot Brian it was the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
      setAlerts : (masg, alertType) => { dispatch(setAlerts (masg, alertType)) }
    }
}


export default connect(null,mapDispatchToProps)(Register)
```

Comment: it gave me this error
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): props.setAlerts is not a function

Comment: can you do a console.log(props) and see what output you get?

Comment: it gave me state undefined

Answer (score 0):

When using Redux, do not export this way in the component.

Change below:

```
export const Register = props => {...}
```

To this:

```
const Register = props => {...}
```

---

You will need to modify this component's import in the App.js.

Change below:

```
import { Register } from '...';
```

To this:

```
import Register from '...';
```